# How can I use Firebase Functions to send FCM to user?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

Firebase currently rolled out **Firebase Functions** to add server side code

[Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)

I was wondering if there could be a way to call FCM notifications through those functions when there is some change in database.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions) includes the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), you can find an example that we made here [Send Firebase Cloud Messaging notifications for new followers](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications)

In brief:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.foo = functions.database.ref('/bar').onWrite(event => {
  const tokens = ...;
  const payload = ...;
  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);  
})
```

Comment: so, for that i would require token of every device.

Comment: Or you could send to a topic, condition, etc. you can find [available methods  on `admin.messaging()` in the reference guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging#methods).

Comment: In my blog post I used a topic-per-user approach: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html. You can replace the Node.js process with Cloud Functions and use the same approach.

Comment: I am currently using this approach everything seems fine but when i kill the app I dont receive notifications. I saw some answers regarding it that i should use just data message and receive in onMessageReceived() but its not working for killed app. What should i do.

Comment: Emm, why multiple returns? Is it a mistake or its something that is supposed to be like that?

Comment: The above code, or any FCM code in a firebase function appears to return the following error: "Error: An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers. Make sure the credential used to authenticate this SDK has the proper permissions. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup for setup instructions."

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is there somewhere a version of similar content for modern cloud functions and FCM? It's been . . . "challenging" to find.