# Send notification to a specific user

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to send a notification when a user receives a message.

**For example**
When user A send a message to user B, I would like that B receives a notification, like in Facebook Messenger.

To do that, I register the FCM TOKEN in my database but I do not know how to send a notification to a specific user with my code.

I saw in the documentation of firebase that they proposes a [FCM SERVER](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) but I do not know how to use it on iOs.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: See [this article on the Firebase blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html) and this [sample in the Cloud Functions documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens), and [this answer showing the latter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42770005/how-can-i-use-firebase-functions-to-send-fcm-to-user).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many tutorials about that online. Found one that might solve your problem:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/140836/firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat-2

In general, all you need is to create channels for your 1-1 messages and push to that channel.

Hope that helps.