# How to send real time device to device notifications using swift 3?

Tags: firebase, swift3, push-notification, onesignal

I am new to Swift and right now I am developing an iOS application which has to send real time user to user notifications. Same like the chat apps, when a user gets a new message, the iPhone has to send a notification. In my case I need only the notifications, but they have to be in real time. When 1 user clicks on a button, the other should receives the notification. I have read many articles and question, but I never found a good example. I have installed OneSignal and FireBase pod files in my app and I can send notifications from their servers to the app, but now I need to send the notifications between the devices.

with the following code I get the userID:

```
func onOSSubscriptionChanged(_ stateChanges: OSSubscriptionStateChanges!) {
    if !stateChanges.from.subscribed && stateChanges.to.subscribed {
        print("Subscribed for OneSignal push notifications!")
    }
    print("SubscriptionStateChange: \n\(stateChanges)")

    //The player id is inside stateChanges. But be careful, this value can be nil if the user has not granted you permission to send notifications.
    if let playerId = stateChanges.to.userId {
        print("Current playerId \(playerId)")
    }
}
```

But how can I use this ID to send a notification to it.
Any examples or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use Firebase Functions to send FCM to user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42770005/how-can-i-use-firebase-functions-to-send-fcm-to-user)

Comment: In order to send device to device messages you will need to set up a webservice to handle your request and send the necessary data to the Firebase service.

Comment: I looked at the link you have sent me, unfortunately it doesn't provide an answer to my problem:(

Comment: @Barns52 any examples?

Comment: Have you created Apple push notiification certificates and configured the Firebase Cloud Notifications APN properly? Also, is Push notifications "ON" in your iOS Project -> Capabilities to enable notification entitlements?

Comment: Yes I have done this for fire base and One signal. As I said I can send push notifications from FireBase and One Signal to the different devices, now I want to send notification between them( between the devices).

Comment: @Dakata: there is no way to send messages directly between devices with FCM. You will need some sort of trusted environment for that, either a server or Cloud Functions. The linked answer shows one easy way to send messages from such a server/Cloud Functions.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen I was thinking to take the userID from Onesignal send it to FireBase and from Firebase to send a notification. That is why I am using both of the services in my app, the problem is that I don't know how to do you. Do you maybe have an example?

Comment: I think you will need to use Firebase DB to store the message and then use Firebase cloud function to push the stored message to the receiver's queue through cloud messaging.

Answer (score 1):

I used Firebase -- it provided all the functionality I needed. I did not investigate onesignal.

I will sketch out the solution I used. Yes, there are other solutions.

You will need a webserver. One from any provider like Strato will do (you could even use your own if you have one). You will at the least need a virtual server.

I use PHP for my webservice. That webservice configures my message to be sent to iOS and Android devices. Because iOS and Android devices handle certain types of messages differently you will need to decide what type of notification will work best for you.

Using the creditials I got from Firebase (Key, Authorisation, URL) I created a config file which I used in all my Firebase notification scripts. I used curl to communicate with the Firebase service

Something like this:

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: key='.$server_key;

//Setup curl, add headers and post parameters.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$error = "0";
//Send the request
$curl_result = curl_exec($ch);
if($curl_result == FALSE){
    $error = curl_error($ch);
}

//Close request
curl_close($ch);
```

You will have a lot of work to do before you can send the actual message --decide what type of message to send (data payload, or just notification). Then format it accordingly. See Firebase documentation for this!

From your device you will need to communicate with the webservice. For this I used `URLRequest` to communicate with the server. Decide how you want to send the request (I used POST) and add your parameters accordingly.

You will want to return a response from your webservice as a response to your request. This is generally done with a JSON string returning info about whether the message was sent successfully. Use the response in your code as needed eg. error handling.

Yes, this is just a sketch. It is a lot of work! But, you will learn a lot by doing it yourself.