# How to send notifications with a phone / Cordova mobile app

Tags: android, jquery, visual-studio, cordova, firebase

I'm new to Cordova and JS stuff, and currently making a Cordova mobile app. The purpose is to send notifications with the help of firebase (I'm focusing on android for now).

**The notification has to be send with a phone, to an other phone.**

I use JQuery Mobile 1.4.5, JQuery 2.1.0 and Cordova CLI 6.1.1

My project is a Visual Studio project (techno restriction)

I'm using this Cordova FCM plugin: https://github.com/ostownsville/cordova-plugin-fcm

---

My code to receive the notifications works pretty well: No errors, token generated successfully, notification received ! (notifications sended by firebase console, with the token, etc.).

**==>** My problem here is that I don't know how to proceed to send notifications to an other phone !

I already have a payload example, that can be use to send the notification. but I don't know how to use it. I'm sure I have to put it in firebase, somewhere, but i don't know where.

Plus, I can't figure how to obtain the token of the phone that I want to send a notification. Is it possible to know the receiver token ?

here is my payload code:

```
 var fcm_server_key = "aiz******************************";

    method: "post",
    datatype: 'json',
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json', 'authorization': 'key=' + fcm_server_key },
    url: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
    data: json.stringify(
        {
            "notification": {
                "title": "title ",  //any value
                "body": "body ",  //any value
                "sound": "default", //if you want notification sound
                "click_action": "fcm_plugin_activity",  //must be present for android
                "icon": "fcm_push_icon"  //white icon android resource
            },
            "data": {
                "param1": "value1",  //any data to be retrieved in the notification callback
                "param2": "value2"
            },
            "to": "<USER_TOKEN>", //topic or device ==> maybe the place to put the token !?
            "priority": "high", //if not set, notification won't be delivered on completely closed ios app
            "restricted_package_name": "" //optional. set for application filtering
        }
      )
```

---

**==>** Is it possible to send notifications with a phone to an other phone, with firebase ? how then :) ?

Finally, I use the the Cordova Contact plugin to list all the contacts in the phone. Is there an other way to show to the user his contacts and then send the notification to the right person ?

---

Thanks a lot for your help. I've already checked the stackoverflow forum and the  plugin issues section in order to solve that problem but I haven't find the solution yet.

(Sorry for bad english, this is my first post...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer to your question there are more levels

> My problem here is that I don't know how to proceed to send
>   notifications to an other phone !

Push notification can be sent through [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/).

> Is it possible to know the receiver token ?

Yes if you Initialize firebase plugin, you will get the firebase token in your javascript function inside `FCMPlugin.getToken()`

> Is it possible to send notifications with a phone to an other phone,
>   with firebase ?

You can send only from one receiver to another receiver directly using firebase push data. But I wont recommend you that. Because it is not safe to exchange data directly between receivers without a server

## Note:

Before starting firebase notification I would like to give you a note. There are 2 types of payloads in firebase.

1.Notification payload : This has a few limitation in receiving notification that, the app will get notification only when app is in background. So notification will not be shown to receiver if he is using the app. It will be handled by your `FCMPlugin`

1.Data payload : If you need to show the notification even if the app is in foreground then go for it. But you need to trigger  the notification manually in your java code in [android way](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/push-notifications-using-firebase-cloud-messaging/)

Comment: Ahhh, thanks a lot for your answer ! But it seems there is a misunderstanding here... I'll explain again :). So, I don't want to send a notification by Firebase console, but by a phone to an other phone. Of course, I have to use Firebase as a server to do it, but I don't know how. I've used firebase console to test my receiving code.  Then, imagine me, I have the phone A and the token AAA and you, you have the phone B with the token BBB (token given by the FCM Server). How can i know that your token is BBB & send you notifications? All I can know with the `getToken()` function is my own token

Comment: In fact, the purpose is to do: `Phone A <---> FCM Server <---> Phone B`           Btw, your "note" section is really interesting :)

Comment: Yaah... obviously you can do it with an intermediate server. If so you have to send the token using ajax to the server on  `FCMPlugin.getToken()` and in server store it with a userID. To send notification from to another phone, send the message and userID to the server, the server will match the userID with its token and notify your message accordingly

Comment: Ok, but I want to use Firebase as my server. Do you know a way to tell firebase: "hey, be my server !". And how can I send my token to firebase (as my server) ? In an ajax post, I have to specify where I want it to go... And if i send my own message to the server, the message will be sent to my phone, because, it's my userID, humm ? or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Hey its going complex. Those cant be given in a single question. There are lot of tutorials for these. check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42772768/6082645) where he had mentioned all the necessary links.