# Send push notifications using FCM after a change in Firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am creating an app that retrieves data from my Cloud Firestore database. If data is added to the database, I want to send users a push notification of that data if they are subscribed to the topic of that data. I am developing using Flutter/Dart and I cant seem to find any useful articles on this. How can I implement something like this using Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Comment: You may want to look into Firebase Cloud Functions, you can use it to listen for events, in your case writes to Firestore and then you can trigger something on Cloud Messaging.

Comment: Hope this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42770005/how-can-i-use-firebase-functions-to-send-fcm-to-user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite straight-forward. There are two steps to it.

Step 1 : Use a Firestore database trigger.

Step 2 : Send the notification.

[This](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) will tell you all about database trigger. It is basically like - whenever there is a create/update/... database transaction, Firestore will execute the code you write.  This page has a couple of sample code as well.

Next is to actually send the notification. You can use the language-specific SDK/library. For example, [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#node.js) contains a node.js package reference to send the notification. The same page also has code snippet for Python, C# and so on. Alternatively, you might wan to  make REST API call in whichever language you use. The details are below :

```
url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'
data = {"notification": { "title": "_____", "body": "_____",}, "to": token}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization':'Key=AAAAOfIU___________'
```

You shall get the authorisation key in your Firebase project (Settings > Project Settings > Cloud Messaging > Project Credential : Server Key).